# I've written Python code that usually works, but an occasional error pops up unexpectedly and then disappears upon rerunning

Tags: python, multithreading, valueerror, vtable

I have written a Python code that works well, but in the middle of using the code, an error occurred. I don't know why, but when I rerun the code, it does not occur again. However, it comes up again in the middle of the code.

Error:

```
PS D:\JARVIS AI> python -u "d:\JARVIS AI\Main\Enhance.py"
Entry Method? Keyboard or Mic: 1

I am Jarvis

Sir: adjust volume
Volume level (0-100): 67

Sir: run plays2.mp3

Jarvis: Terminal or App? 1

Sir: half volume
Exception ignored in: <function _compointer_base.__del__ at 0x000002A548589BC0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 614, in __del__
    self.Release()
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 847, in Release
    return self.__com_Release()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: COM method call without VTable
Exception ignored in: <function _compointer_base.__del__ at 0x000002A548589BC0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 614, in __del__
    self.Release()
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 847, in Release
    return self.__com_Release()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: COM method call without VTable

Sir: adjust volume
Volume level (0-100): 44
```

Then after some time this error come again.

Code:

```py
import os
import datetime

if __name__ == "__main__":
    method = method()
    if method == "keyboard" or method == "1":
        enter = from_keyboard
    else:
        enter = from_microphone

    print("\nI am Jarvis")
    speak("I am Jarvis")
    
    while True:
        try:
            speak("Sir:")           
            print("\nSir: ", end="")
            query = enter()
            
            elif "run" in query:
                query = query.replace("run","",1).strip()            
                
                if file_locator(query) is not None:
                               
                    while True:
                        speak("Sir, In terminal or app?")
                        print("\nJarvis: Terminal or App? ", end="")
                        play = enter()
 
                        if "app" in play or "2" in play or "default" in play:                 
                            default_run(file_locator(query))
                            break
                        elif "terminal" in play or "1" in play or "inside" in play:
                            
                            if any(ext in query for ext in [".mp4", ".mkv"]):
                                default_run(file_locator(query))
                                break
                            elif any(ext in query for ext in [".mp3", ".wav"]):
                                inbuilt_sound(file_locator(query))
                                break
                            elif any(ext in query for ext in [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png"]):
                                inbuilt_image(file_locator(query))
                                break
                            else:
                                default_run(file_locator(query))
                                break
                        else:
                            speak("Invalid Input")
                            print("\nJarvis: Invalid Input")   

            elif any(keyboard in query for keyboard in ["adjust volume", "half volume", "mute", "max volume", "full volume"]):
                if "adjust volume" in query:
                    while True:
                        print('Volume level (0-100): ', end="")
                        speak('Enter the Volume level')
                        vol = enter()
                        if vol.isnumeric() and int(vol) >= 0:
                            vol = int(vol)
                            adjust(vol / 100)
                            speak(f"Volume set to {vol} persent")
                            break
                        elif vol < 0:
                            print("\nJarvis: Invalid Input\n")
                            speak("Invalid Input")
                        else:
                            print("\nJarvis: Invalid, Choose a number\n")
                            speak("Invalid, Choose a number")
                elif "mute" in query:
                    speak("Volume is going muted")
                    adjust(0)
                    
                elif any(keyword in query for keyword in ["max volume", "full volume"]):
                    adjust(1)
                    speak("Volume set to max")
                    
                elif "half volume" in query:
                    adjust(0.5)
                    speak("Volume set to half")
                
            elif "api use" in query:
                speak("Showing..")
                webbrowser.get(edge_path).open("https://platform.openai.com/account/usage")
                comeback()

        except Exception as e:
            print("Jarvis: ",e)
            pass
```

Adjust Volume Function:

```py
def adjust(vol):
    from ctypes import POINTER, cast
    from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
    from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume

    devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
    interface = devices.Activate(IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
    volume_object = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
    volume_object.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(vol, None)
```

Video Player Function:

```py
import threading
import playsound

def inbuilt_sound(location):
    try:
        def sound():
            playsound.playsound(location)
        
        sound_thread = threading.Thread(target=sound)
        sound_thread.start()
    except:
        print("Error, try again.")
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Make sure your code compiles. I've removed the random lines of dots, but I still don't think you're providing a [mcve]. People need to be able to reproduce the problem to help you.